# javascript - Jquery toggle error in Internet Explorer 8 and below

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

In internet explorer <=8 i got toggle error. I am using jquery-1.7.1. Thanks!
JS code:

```
function myFunction1() {
    document.getElementById("dropdown-content1").classList.toggle("show");
}
```

So when press `<a onclick="myFunction1()" id="shopbtn" href="#">Shop</a>` it should add `show` class to block with id `dropdown-content1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't using any jQuery functions in that code. Everything in it is standard JavaScript and DOM.

`classList` is [too new for IE8 to support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=classlist) (and [IE8 is too old for Microsoft to support](http://thenextweb.com/microsoft/2016/01/05/web-developers-rejoice-internet-explorer-8-9-and-10-die-on-tuesday/)).

If you wanted to use jQuery then you could use:

```
jQuery("#dropdown-content").toggleClass("show");
```